google script array evaluating to null
This function is intended to send an an email notification regarding the number of "tardies" that a student has. This is an adaptation of a similar function I've been using reliably, which is not working. I'm running into issues when setting the variable gradeNameList. When trying to use the for loop and if function to scan for a match, the array is evaluating to null. I prepared this sample sheet. When executing the function, I'm expecting an email to go out to "1666@usa.org" and CC g@hotmail.com. Insights will be well received.
function likeMessage() {
  
  var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1giEC08YlkXhwIibHt30BdDJmuwwlq9ZzfQdhkQETogo'); 
  var tardyTrackerSheet = mainSheet.getSheetByName('new_tardy_tracker_form_responses'); 
  var tardyTrackerLastRow = tardyTrackerSheet.getLastRow(); 
    
  var teacher = tardyTrackerSheet.getRange(tardyTrackerLastRow, 2).getValue();  
  var tardyBlock = tardyTrackerSheet.getRange(tardyTrackerLastRow, 7).getValue();
  var grade = tardyTrackerSheet.getRange(tardyTrackerLastRow, 3).getValue();
      
  var gradeColumn; //declared a variable, so we can tweak it next...
  
  var adminTeam = ""; 

  if (grade == "sixth") { 
    gradeColumn = 3;
    adminTeam = "g@hotmail.com";
  } else if (grade == "seventh") {
    gradeColumn = 4;
    adminTeam = "do@lcps.org";
  } else if (grade == "eighth") {
    gradeColumn = 5;
    adminTeam = "j@lcps.org";
  }

  var studentName = tardyTrackerSheet.getRange(tardyTrackerLastRow, gradeColumn).getValue();
  
  var gradeSheet = mainSheet.getSheetByName(grade); 

  var gradeSheetLastRow = gradeSheet.getLastRow();  
  var gradeNameList = gradeSheet.getRange(2, 1, (gradeSheetLastRow - 1)).getValues();
  var studentRow = 0; //declaring, to use below
  var flag = true;
  
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < gradeSheetLastRow; i++) { 
    if (gradeNameList[i] == studentName) {
      studentRow = i + 2;
      }
    else {
      flag = false;  
    }
  }
    

  var emailMessage = "";
  var studentId = "";
  var studentEmail = "";
  var currentTotalTardies = "";
  var parentEmails = "";

  if (flag){
    studentId = gradeSheet.getRange(studentRow, 2).getValues();  
    studentEmail = studentId +"@lcps.org";  
    currentTotalTardies = gradeSheet.getRange(studentRow, 19).getValues(); 
    parentEmails = gradeSheet.getRange(studentRow, 20).getValues(); 
      
    emailMessage = "Dear sir, etc.";  

      MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: studentEmail,
      cc: adminTeam,
      subject: receivedLikeSubject,
      htmlBody: receivedLikeMessage
      });
  }     
}


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About I'm running into issues when setting the variable gradeNameList. When trying to use the for loop and if function to scan for a match, the array is evaluating to null., when I tested your script using your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that gradeNameList is not null.

Also, about I prepared this sample sheet. When executing the function, I'm expecting an email to go out to "1666@usa.org" and CC g@hotmail.com., when I saw your script and your sheet new_tardy_tracker_form_responses, I cannot find email of 1666@usa.org. Where can I see it? From these situations, I'm worried that you might have misplaced your script or spreadsheet. Can you confirm them again? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Try it this way:
function likeMessage() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const msh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1giEC08YlkXhwIibHt30BdDJmuwwlq9ZzfQdhkQETogo');
  const tsh = msh.getSheetByName('new_tardy_tracker_form_responses');
  const tshlr = tsh.getLastRow();
  const [, teacher, grade, , , , tardyBlock] = tsh.getRange(tshlr, 1, 1, 7).getValues();
  const obj = { "sixth": { "column": 3, "team": "g@hotmail.com" }, "seventh": { "column": 4, "team": "do@lcps.org" }, "eighth": { "column": 5, "team": "j@lcps.org" } };
  const gradeColumn = obj[grade].column;
  const adminTeam = obj[grade].team;
  var studentName = tsh.getRange(tshlr, gradeColumn).getValue();
  var gsh = msh.getSheetByName(grade);
  var gshlr = gsh.getLastRow();
  var gList = gsh.getRange(2, 1, (gshlr - 1)).getValues().flat();
  var srow = 0;
  var flag = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < gshlr; i++) {
    if (gList[i] == studentName) {
      srow = i + 2;
    }
    else {
      flag = false;
    }
  }
  var emailMessage = "";
  var studentId = "";
  var studentEmail = "";
  var currentTotalTardies = "";
  var parentEmails = "";
  if (flag) {
    studentId = gsh.getRange(srow, 2).getValue();
    studentEmail = studentId + "@lcps.org";
    currentTotalTardies = gsh.getRange(srow, 19).getValue();
    parentEmails = gsh.getRange(srow, 20).getValue();
    emailMessage = "Dear sir, etc.";
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: studentEmail,
      cc: adminTeam,
      subject: receivedLikeSubject,
      htmlBody: receivedLikeMessage
    });
  }
}

